# How to return a json "object" instead of a json "array" with Active Model ArraySerializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, active-model-serializers

Using Active Model Serializer, is there an easy and integrated way to return a JSON "object" (that would then be converted in a javascript object by the client framework) instead of a JSON "array" when serializing a collection? (I am quoting object and array, since the returned JSON is by essence a string).

Let's say I have the following ArticleSerializer:

```
class ArticleSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :body, :posted_at, :status, :teaser, :title
end
```

I call it from ArticlesController:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @feed = Feed.new(articles: Article.all)
    render json: @feed.articles, each_serializer: ArticleSerializer
  end
end
```

Is there a way to pass an option to the serializer to make it return something like:

```
{"articles":
  {
    "1":{ 
      ...
    },
    "2":{
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

instead of

```
{"articles":
  [
    { 
      "id":"1",
      ...
    },
    {
      "id":"2"
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

---

Edit: I guess that the approach proposed in this post (subclassing AMS ArraySerializer) might be helpful ([Active Model Serializer and Custom JSON Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20587388/active-model-serializer-and-custom-json-structure))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to write a custom adapter to suit your format.
Alternatively, you could modify the hash before passing it to `render`.
If you do not mind iterating over the resulting hash, you could do:

```
ams_hash = ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(@articles)
                                            .serializable_hash
result_hash = ams_hash['articles'].map { |article| { article['id'] => article.except(:id) } }
                                  .reduce({}, :merge)
```

Or, if you'd like this to be the default behavior, I'd suggest switching to the `Attributes` adapter (which is exactly the same as the `Json` adapter, except there is no document root), and override the `serializable_hash` method as follows:

```
 def format_resource(res)
   { res['id'] => res.except(:id) }
 end

 def serializable_hash(*args)
   hash = super(*args)
   if hash.is_a?(Array)
     hash.map(&:format_resource).reduce({}, :merge)
   else
     format_resource(hash)
   end
 end
```

Comment: You're right. Looking at the source code, no such option seem available. I guess I have to amend method serializable_hash_for_collection in the json_api adapter [link](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/lib/active_model/serializer/adapter/json_api.rb). Or modify the hash, using a RegEx for the best performance. Or iterate over my collection of Articles and call the single item serializer on each of them and wrap them up in a hash before passing it to render. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @Cedric Have a look at the solution I just sketched!

Comment: this looks really good. I'll give it a try tomorrow and will let you know if works, but it looks really good. Merci beaucoup!

Answer (score 0):

No, semantically you are returning an array of Articles. Hashes are simply objects in Javascript, so you essentially want an object with a 1..n method that returns each Article, but that would not make much sense.

Comment: Thanks. It might not make sense but it is exactly what I am forced to do in my js framework with normalizrjs... And this pattern of storing array-like structures as flat objects is the way flat database store their data. I could write a hand-made serializer that would iterate over each of my articles, fetch their ID, pass them individually to the AMS serializer, and build a JSON flat object/hash out of them before passing them back to the controller, and then render it as JSON. But performance-wise... The purpose is to alleviate the front-end. I might try a REGEX instead.